# Subdomain on Windows

Tags: windows, dns

My `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file looks like this:

```
192.168.52.128 website.localhost
192.168.52.128 website-test
```

When I go to the address `website.localhost` in browser, it does not respond. When I go to the address `192.168.52.128` or `website-test` everything works fine.

Could you let me know why `website.localhost` does not respond in the browser?

PS. When I `ping website.localhost` or `curl website.localhost`, I got a response.

I am working on the windows 10.

192.168.52.128 - this is ip address of virtual box.

Comment: You already posted this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66354543/subdomain-of-localhost-on-windows. Delete this question and edit the other question to meet Stackoverflow's guidelines. Repeating a closed question will result in another closed question.

Comment: Note: You are trying to remap `localhost` to an external network. That is not supported by the IP stack. `localhost` is only available inside the machine.